# Return data ID upon uploading Image in angular ts and firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Im uploading an image using `angularTS` and `firebase`. my plan is to upload an image and saved the following data. after that I expect a return `ID` from the `firebase database` callback. problem is, I can't get the data because it return to me like this.

```
__zone_symbol__state : true
__zone_symbol__value : "viHnY2OpUnJkO2VbfgwJ"
__proto__ : Object
```

this is my code for uploading image.

```
 this.venueSvc.setVenuePhoto(this.venue, this.photo[0])
      .subscribe(snapshot => {
       console.log(snapshot); 
       console.log(snapshot.__zone_symbol__value);
       console.log(snapshot.value);

 });
```

and this is my service to upload the image to firebase database.

```
setVenuePhoto(venue: any, photo: File): Observable<any> {
    console.log(venue);

    let subjectTemp: any;
    let uploadPhoto: any;

    const uploadTask = firebase.storage()
      .ref().child(this.PATH_VENUES + '/' + photo.name)
      .put(photo);

    uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
      uploadPhoto = snapshot;
      let progress = Math.floor((uploadPhoto.bytesTransferred / uploadPhoto.totalBytes) * 100);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    }, () => {

      venue.dateCreated = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
      venue.dateUpdated = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
      venue.venuePhoto = uploadPhoto.task.snapshot.downloadURL;

      subjectTemp = this.venuesCollection.add(<Venue>venue.getData()).then(value => {
        return value.id
      });

      this.viewUploadSubject.next(subjectTemp);
    });

    return this.viewUploadSubject;
  }
```

I should be able to get the ID because im gonna need it to update the venue. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading your image to Storage, not Firebase. They are two different services, and Storage doesn't provide and ID for file that you update.

If you want to reference an file from Storage, you can just save It's path.

Or you can save an reference for this file on Firebase so that you can get references from files more easily.

Comment: ok. did you read my codes. its after i upload the image to storage. then ill save the filepath to my firebasedb.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the downloadUrl in the database instead of the id

`uploadPhoto.task.snapshot.downloadURL`

I don't know the structure of the rest of your app but you could save the downloadURL either update the db in your complete method on the upload
`uploadTask.on('state_changed', progress, error, complete);`
or save it the downloadUrl in state and after the upload save the url to the database

Comment: Hi @Peter. I already did that. if you examine my code. you can see that I save the snapshot url to database. now after saving the snapshot url data. I expect that id will return to me. then after that. im going to use callback to retrieve the id from the component so I can use that id to whatever necessary..